# Replace text between brackets

Tags: perl, replace, awk, sed, find

This is the first time I've tried to do this from a Mac (I use repl.bat on Windows) and I'm struggling to figure out the correct syntax to do this.

Basically, I have in a file called defines.h that has stuff like this in it:

```
#define GAME_VERSION (2060)
#define TESTHOOK
#define PRERELEASE
#define pi      3.1415926536f
#define FX32_ONE    (4096)
```

And I want to replace the text between the brackets or after the equals with a passed in environment variable (I also want to replace things like GAME_VERSION= in other files)

I've been trying to use sed, perl and awk but can't seem to get the syntax right. Could someone talk me through this please?

I have managed to do this so far:

```
echo "GAME_VERSION (2000)" | sed s/'([^)]*)'/'3000'/g
```

The first 2 replies haven't changed the defines.h file at all and I'm not sure if I'm doing something else wrong or because I didn't show more of the file's contents before. Not sure if relevant but the contents of defines.h get printed to the terminal console also.

Comment: You need to do `sed -i ...` to get it to write it's output back to the original file. man sed.

Answer (score 1):

That should work with both formats:

```
REPLACE="5000"
sed "s/\([(=]\)\([0-9]\+\)/\1$REPLACE/g" defines.h
```

Gives the output:

```
GAME_VERSION (5000)
GAME_VERSION=5000
```

It searches for a bracket or a equal sign (`[(=]`) followed by a digit (`[0-9]\+`) and replaces it by the contentss of the environment variable `$REPLACE`.

Comment: `g` is optionel in this case but it's ok assuming there is only 1 assigned value

Answer (score 1):

in thios specific case
NewValue=713705

```
sed "/^[[:space:]]*GAME_VERSION/ s/[0-9]*/${NewValue}/" define.h
```

assuming:

- there are more than 1 line in define.h that can have number assigned
- there is only 1 uncommented for GAME_VERSION